# Countifs order no. which has more than 1 item in basket

Tags: google-sheets, filter, count, unique, google-sheets-formula

I have a set of order data where I'm looking to understand whether an order took advantage of an onsite offer.

Here is an example of the data:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zx8HMuSYzGKvJYD7PclsN_KXHN0RmYoG7spRkxqai_U/edit?usp=sharing

So the offer has a min item purchase of 2. I want to count the unique orders which have >1 offer items in their order.

Because each item is on a new line I'm struggling to check whether the order has more than 1 offer item.

I need it to be in a singular formula if possible. I tried a few examples like:

```
countunique(iferror(filter(salesData!$C$2:$C,aata!$D$2:$D="Yes")))
```

However, no version I have tried can I work out how to check the condition noted above.

Sample Data:

```
Date      Channel   No.   Offer  
26/03/2020  Online  353484  Yes  
26/03/2020  Online  353484  Yes  
26/03/2020  Online  353484  Yes  
26/03/2020  Online  353415  Yes  
26/03/2020  Online  353415  Yes  
28/03/2020  Online  353762  Yes  
29/03/2020  Online  353830  Yes  
29/03/2020  Online  353868  Yes  
27/03/2020  Online  353640  No   
28/03/2020  Online  353663  No  
26/03/2020  Online  353529  Yes  
26/03/2020  Online  353529  Yes  
25/03/2020  Online  353231  No  
23/03/2020  Online  352957  No  
27/03/2020  Online  353627  No  
27/03/2020  Online  353568  No  
25/03/2020  Online  353378  No  
28/03/2020  Online  353671  No  
27/03/2020  Online  353547  No  
29/03/2020  Online  353790  No  
27/03/2020  Online  353625  Yes  
27/03/2020  Online  353625  Yes  
27/03/2020  Online  353584  No  
28/03/2020  Online  353683  No  
26/03/2020  Online  353530  No  
23/03/2020  Online  353056  No
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try:

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(IFNA(FILTER(data!C2:C, COUNTIFS(
 data!C2:C&data!D2:D, data!C2:C&data!D2:D, 
 data!D2:D, "yes", 
 ROW(data!C2:C), "<="&ROW(data!C2:C))>1)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Why should I, or anyone else for that matter, "try" this code? Please remember that you are not only answering to the OP, but also to any future readers of this post and [edit] the answer to include an explanation. See [answer].

Comment: Hi @Adriaan I think the answer may have been vague as player0 messaged me on the google sheet explaining.